# cannot insert to mysql database from android fragment

Tags: android, mysql, android-fragmentactivity, android-database

I am creating form in fragment to insert data into MySQL. But what is error in this code ? Data can not been submitted. Android studio doesn't generate any error also. I think any part to connect with server is missing. I've checked php code, everything works fine. Following is fragment activity code

```
public class News_Yeb extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    String DataParseUrl = "http://fitandfineindustries.com.np/insert.php" ;
    Boolean CheckEditText ;
    private static View view;
    EditText name,email,contact ;
    String Getname,GetEmail,GetContact ;
    private static Button signUpButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_yeb, container, false);
        initViews();
        setListeners();
        return view;
        }

    // Initialize all views
    private void initViews() {
        name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fullName);
        email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userEmailId);
        contact = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.mobileNumber);
        signUpButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.signUpBtn);

    }

    // Set Listeners
    private void setListeners() {
        signUpButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        GetCheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();


        if(CheckEditText){

            SendDataToServer(Getname, GetEmail, GetContact);

        }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please fill all form fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }


    // Check Validation Method
    private void GetCheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot() {

        // Get all edittext texts
        String Getname  = name.getText().toString();
        String GetEmail  = email.getText().toString();
        String GetContact = contact.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Getname) || TextUtils.isEmpty(GetEmail) || TextUtils.isEmpty(GetContact))
        {

            CheckEditText = false;

        }
        else {

            CheckEditText = true ;
        }

    }

    public void SendDataToServer(final String name, final String email, final String contact){
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String QuickName = name ;
                String QuickEmail = email ;
                String QuickContact = contact;

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", QuickName));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", QuickEmail));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contact", QuickContact));

                try {

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(DataParseUrl);

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    URL url = new URL("http://fitandfineindustries.com.np/insert.php");
                    URLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());


                }
                return "Data Submit Successfully";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Submitted Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(name, email, contact);
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you sure ```insert.php``` being called? Have you checked to see what parameters are being sent to it? Is it generating any errors?

Comment: Yeah I checked it php code is working